# Show unread/read messages

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, flags

I have a sample code for receive messages from gmail server.
I can show them on my listview by my custom listview adapter. Now, I want to set their images like "seen" or "recent". For example; I open a message from my gmail account. And then open my project on my emulator. I want to set the mail's image is set as "seen" image. If a new mail fall into my gmail inbox, then on my listview the mail should has a"recent" image.

I used this code for this issue. But I am assuming it was the wrong code block because my all "recent" mails become "seen" mails

```
 public List<String> RecentorReadMessage(Message[] messages) {
            try {

                for (int i = messages.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                    if (messages[i]
                            .isSet(Flags.Flag.RECENT)) {
                        messageImageView.add("yeni");
    //                  imgmessageDurum.setImageResource(R.drawable.okunmadi80x80);

                    } else if (messages[i]
                            .isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)) {
                        messageImageView.add("eski");
    //                  imgmessageDurum.setImageResource(R.drawable.okundu80x80);
                    }
                }
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return messageImageView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Gmail doesn't support the IMAP \Recent flag.](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78761&topic=1668982&ctx=topic)